# Linux RTSP server

Tags: linux, rtsp

We plan to build the video streaming solution. Servers should take an rtsp stream from cams and duplicate it to users. Users connects to the authentication servers and only then are redirected to video servers. Video servers gives a stream to users through the https in browser.

Our problem: how to organize the streaming part? It is impossible to make every time a new session with cameras, because after some sessions amount the cameras just die.

Is it a good idea to insert a data about already taken stream into MySQL and before give stream to new user check the MySQL for if the stream already exists. If yes so duplicate the stream from another server, not from camera. But what if the thirst stream will be closed (user closes the web browser)?

All ideas will be appreciated.

Regards,
Mic.

Answer (score 1):

Two obvious choices are [Adobe Flash Media Server](http://www.adobe.com/products/flashmediaserver/) and [Red5](http://osflash.org/red5) - open source and free.
FMS is a better and more advanced product, while red5 is free, written in java, and is open source.